# Incorrect email encoding with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, encoding, codeigniter-2

Now the data looks like this in the database:

> Hej [indtaster_navn]<br><br>I forbindelse med noget på ændring af xxxxxx er der behov for opfølgning på:<br><br>- xxxx<br>- xxxx<br>- xxxx<br><br>Jeg vil gerne have en tilbagemelding, når du har set på ovenstående.<br/><br/>Venlig hilsen<br/>[behandler_navn]<br/>TestGuy<br/><br/>[lokal_tlf] - lokal<br>00 00 00 00 - telefon<br>[behandler_email]<br><br>This S<br>Something<br>Transformer 1234<br>3434 BubbleJ<br><br>​​​​

So i have following code when sending a mail, where it's important to notice that i use `html_entity_decode`:

```
    $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
    $config['priority'] = 1;
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($this->auth_data->user_email, $this->auth_data->user_firstname . ' ' . $this->auth_data->user_lastname);
    $this->email->reply_to($this->auth_data->user_email, $this->auth_data->user_firstname . ' ' . $this->auth_data->user_lastname);
    $this->email->to('test@test.com'); 
    $this->email->subject($feedback_title_temp);
    $this->email->message(html_entity_decode($feedback_temp));  
    $this->email->send();
```

When i receive the email it inserts the symbol `=` random places and in some cases the `<br>` does not even occur.

For example:

```
- xxxx<=r>- xxxx
```

Should be:

```
- xxxx
- xxxx
```

When i view the email on my smartphone, the encoding problem only seems to occur with the `æåø` chars while Outlook is a completely different story.

Received email header::

```
**Microsoft Mail Internet Headers Version 2.0
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?(ID:_418)?=
To: some@one.com
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 0:Email.php
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 7 Nov 2012 00:31:54 +0100
From: <mat@damn.com>
Return-Path: <mat@damn.com>
Reply-To: "Johnny Bravo" <mat@damn.com>
X-Sender: damn@test.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 1 (Highest)
Message-ID: <50999deab797d@test.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_50999deab798e"
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 06 Nov 2012 23:31:54.0823 (UTC) FILETIME=[E8022570:01CDBC76]

--B_ALT_50999deab798e
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

--B_ALT_50999deab798e
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable


--B_ALT_50999deab798e--
**
```

Received mail, based on different content, but the errors are very obvious:

```
Det her er en m=sse tekst, det er bare en test fra en hæææst.


- Hehe
- Heh<=br>
- Wee


A=l these things

- Lots of text
```

Comment: What encoding is your database? Also the script file encoding can affect this after my experience.

Comment: The encoding of my database is `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: Is the php file saved as utf-8 also?

Comment: Why did you encode html entities before put it to database?

Comment: @zerkms, i dont encode anything. I assume that CodeIgniter does that for security reasons. As far as i can see that is not the problem.

Comment: @JavaCake: CI doesn't do that by default. And this has nothing to do with security at all. I asked you because it makes no sense to encode it before storing to database and decode after retrieval. The more logic you add to the process - the more things you need to debug to find the root of the issue.

Comment: @zerkms, as far as i could understand from multiple threads the `set_value` function which im using in my model does the filtering/encoding. I am saving data from a WYSIWYG textarea. The field is able to decode the encoded data from the database flawless.

Comment: @zerkms, i even tried to replace `set_value('blah')` with `$_POST['blah']` but with same result. I rechecked all files, and they are `UTF-8`. I had similiar code running on my own computer, which seems to work fine with the encoding.

Comment: Furthermore i can confirm that html_entity_encode is doing correct encoding when i parse in a HTML document. So i assume that something goes quite wrong in the email process.

Comment: Can we see the entire received email message?

Comment: @seangates, i have added an example of a mail. As you can see there is `=` char random places. Does it have something to do with the 8-bit header encoding?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );
```

Fixed the problem!

Comment: That's a life savior!